# sklearn SVC throwing "reshape error" upon execution

Tags: scikit-learn, svm, sklearn-pandas

**Context**

I'm trying to use the methods in this cross validation [article](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/cross_validation.html) on my own data (imported from a csv, no missing values, all interpolated, no missing, some 0's, some negatives to positive ranges, mostly positive ranges).  The initial data has a missing header and footer row due to offsetting using shift but is taken care of with the [1:,][:-1] in the train_test_split function.

Any way I try to include the code on my own data, an error is thrown.  I'm able to use the train_test_split function to split my data for most other functions and I suspect the error is related to the way the data is structured?

[link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1YakZm2jx1nwY93Bumi4wya5DknQfbmgd/view?usp=sharing) to csv

being read as

```
input_file = "parsed.csv"

df = pd.read_csv(input_file, header = 0)


x = df.loc[0:,[
...
]]
```

...

```
model_testing = sm.OLS(model_training.predict(X_test),y_test,missing='drop').fit()
```

**I originally tried.**

```
clf = svm.SVC(kernel='linear', C=1).fit(X_train,y_train)
```

**Which throws error**

```
/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sklearn/utils/validation.py:578: DataConversionWarning: A column-vector y was passed when a 1d array was expected. Please change the shape of y to (n_samples, ), for example using ravel().
  y = column_or_1d(y, warn=True)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                
Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-435-eae5045a136b> in <module>
```

So I looked at the original code in the URL and saw the shape parameters were different than mine.  So I tried to "flatten" them (1d), yet got a different error.

**Code**

```
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(set1.loc[1:,][:-1], yFutureYield.loc[1:,][:-1], test_size=0.25)

model_testing = sm.OLS(model_training.predict(X_test),y_test,missing='drop').fit()

print(X_train.shape)
print(y_train.shape)
print(X_train.head(5))
print(y_train.head(5))

clf = svm.SVC(kernel='linear', C=1).fit(np.array(X_train).flatten(), 
np.array(y_train).flatten())
```

**produces**

```
(285, 47)
(285, 1)
     CSUSHPISA  CUUR0000SETB01  DCOILBRENTEU  RECPROUSM156N  CPIHOSNS  \
149     96.004          98.600     15.863182           0.02   164.100   
272    148.031         220.542     67.646190           0.34   217.178   
171    111.653         132.800     25.657143          32.02   175.400   
187    123.831         120.900     26.651364           0.52   181.700   
309    143.607         322.934    111.710870           0.02   223.708   

     CPALTT01USM661S  PAYNSA  CUUR0000SEHA  CPIAUCSL  LNS12300060     ...      \
149        70.037170  130150       177.100   166.000         81.4     ...       
272        91.074058  130589       248.965   215.861         75.1     ...       
171        74.425041  132349       190.200   176.400         80.9     ...       
187        76.154875  130356       200.200   180.500         79.3     ...       
309        97.730543  135649       262.707   231.638         76.1     ...       

     CUUR0000SEHA      CPIAUCSL  LNS12300060      GS5  CUUR0000SETA01  \
149  31293.570000  27556.000000      6625.96  31.6064    20363.250000   
272  61999.504985  46506.173145      5677.56   6.0909    18043.950080   
171  36061.920000  31064.040000      6577.17  22.0864    20377.560000   
187  39999.960000  32490.000000      6272.63  12.5349    19154.470000   
309  68677.126647  53511.852570      5783.60   0.4757    20697.980975   

         CPILFESL      CPILFENS  PCECTPICTM  CSUSHPINSA  CSUSHPINSA  
149  31169.900000  31187.560000      4.2025      96.393   -0.010515  
272  48271.560320  48341.204652      4.2025     149.631    0.006909  
171  34187.970000  34391.680000      4.2025     111.248   -0.007727  
187  36404.550000  36347.300000      4.2025     124.729   -0.008424  
309  53287.764816  53373.875280      4.2025     143.977    0.002688  

[5 rows x 47 columns]
     CSUSHPINSA
149    0.008579
272   -0.006950
171    0.008584
187    0.006125
309   -0.000042
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

**Error**

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-433-9ef18f8c2bef> in <module>
     90 #np.array(y_train).flatten()
     91 #dir(model_training)
---> 92 clf = svm.SVC(kernel='linear', C=1).fit(np.array(X_train).flatten(), np.array(y_train).flatten())
     93 
     94 #deltas

/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sklearn/svm/base.py in fit(self, X, y, sample_weight)
    147         self._sparse = sparse and not callable(self.kernel)
    148 
--> 149         X, y = check_X_y(X, y, dtype=np.float64, order='C', accept_sparse='csr')
    150         y = self._validate_targets(y)
    151 

/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sklearn/utils/validation.py in check_X_y(X, y, accept_sparse, dtype, order, copy, force_all_finite, ensure_2d, allow_nd, multi_output, ensure_min_samples, ensure_min_features, y_numeric, warn_on_dtype, estimator)
    571     X = check_array(X, accept_sparse, dtype, order, copy, force_all_finite,
    572                     ensure_2d, allow_nd, ensure_min_samples,
--> 573                     ensure_min_features, warn_on_dtype, estimator)
    574     if multi_output:
    575         y = check_array(y, 'csr', force_all_finite=True, ensure_2d=False,

/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sklearn/utils/validation.py in check_array(array, accept_sparse, dtype, order, copy, force_all_finite, ensure_2d, allow_nd, ensure_min_samples, ensure_min_features, warn_on_dtype, estimator)
    439                     "Reshape your data either using array.reshape(-1, 1) if "
    440                     "your data has a single feature or array.reshape(1, -1) "
--> 441                     "if it contains a single sample.".format(array))
    442             array = np.atleast_2d(array)
    443             # To ensure that array flags are maintained

ValueError: Expected 2D array, got 1D array instead:
array=[  9.60040000e+01   9.86000000e+01   1.58631818e+01 ...,   4.20250000e+00
   1.56299000e+02  -7.67852077e-03].
Reshape your data either using array.reshape(-1, 1) if your data has a single feature or array.reshape(1, -1) if it contains a single sample.
```

Comment: Can you tell what Xtrain and Ytrain look like so we can reproduce the error?

Comment: what do you need?  I thought the head command was enough.  A type command?  A link to the original csv?

Comment: Ideally a DataFrame constructor helps otherwise it's difficult to go from the head() to a dataframe.

Comment: df = pd.read_csv(input_file, header = 0)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use:

```
clf = svm.SVR(kernel='linear', C=1).fit(X_train,y_train.values.flatten())
```

Comment: ...
     88 #pd.DataFrame.from_records(deltas)
     89 type(deltas)
---> 90 y_train.reshape(len(y_train),1)
/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/generic.py in __getattr__(self, name)
   4374             if self._info_axis._can_hold_identifiers_and_holds_name(name):
   4375                 return self[name]
-> 4376             return object.__getattribute__(self, name)
   4377 
   4378     def __setattr__(self, name, value):

AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'reshape'

Comment: DataFrame.values.reshape() if it is  dataframe.

Comment: clf = svm.SVC(kernel='linear', C=1).fit(X_train,y_train.values.reshape(len(y_train),1)) results in /opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sklearn/utils/validation.py:578: DataConversionWarning: A column-vector y was passed when a 1d array was expected. Please change the shape of y to (n_samples, ), for example using ravel().
  y = column_or_1d(y, warn=True)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError          (google drive url with parsed.csv)

Comment: how are set1 and yfutureyield constructed?

Comment: Ok I just played all your code, when running the simplified version clf = svm.SVC(kernel='linear', C=1).fit(X_train,y_train), i get a different error related to the classifier, it complains SVC cannot do continuous variables, and it makes sense because it is a classifier and the output variable continuos, I chaned it for SVR which is the regressor and it worked.

Comment: ah.  I'm new to SVR and SVC.  I know about DSS and I suspect this is similar to a classifier or regressor DSS setup.  Can you modify your answer to fit the original context, I'm not sure what you did.

Comment: I just left the piece that works, now the data is reproducible so that line is the one that matters.

Comment: clf = svm.SVR(kernel='linear', C=1).fit(X_train, y_train.values.flatten())
print(clf.score(X_test, y_test))
thank you!